# .Net Core on Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, asp.net-core-mvc, raspbian

Is it possible to install .Net Core on **Raspberry Pi 4** with **Raspbian**? I found a number of instructions about .Net Core on Raspberry Pi 3 e.g. (https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md) or .Net Core on Raspberry Pi with Linux. I have already installed Visual Studio Code and now I want to install .Net Core. Please share your experience and method if you installed .Net Core on **Raspberry Pi 4** with **Raspbian**. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already attempted to install .Net Core on a Pi 4? Or are you trying to decide on purchasing a Pi 4, and you want to know if .Net Core will be fine on it?

Answer (score 9):

Download .Net Core 3.1 SDK from [HERE](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

**Make Directory:**

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/dotnet/
```

**PATH to environment:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet 
export DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
```

or just a symlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

**Copy by Extracting:**

```
sudo tar zxf dotnet-sdk-3.1.100-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet/
```

**Confirm Installation:**

```
dotnet --info
```

you can find in detail from [Here](http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.com/2020/01/how-to-install-net-core-31-on-raspberry.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed. The problem was that Raspbian just supports ARM32. https://youtu.be/8Qh4OXQdcZQ

Comment: yes raspberry pi 3 supports only ARM32. As I had and used only raspberry pi3.

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet