# How to run .net core 3.1 app on Raspberry PI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, .net-core-3.1

What I tried:

1. Create default empty asp.net core project in VS 2019, it targets .Net Core 3.1
2. Run: `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm --self-contained` (also tried without --self-contained, both produce exactly the same artifacts)
3. Copy the contents of `bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\linux-arm\publish` to Raspberry PI
4. Download and extract [ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) (Linux Binaries ARM32) on my Raspberry PI
5. Run my app: `dotnet WebApplication1.dll`

And I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin/testApp $ dotnet WebApplication1.dll
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (WebApplication1.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-arm', version: '3.1.0'
    path: 'createdump'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry for the delay, did you checked `dotnet --info` in terminal

Comment: @Vara nope, what should I be looking for in the info?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I mean that did you installed .net core runtime. or did you added path in env. For installing .net core SDK pls look hear https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612857/7553342

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue some time ago, one solution that worked for me, was to place the following lines in the .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help