# running dotnet on raspberry pi B with debian does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, raspberry-pi, debian

It is an original Raspberry pi B, quite old. I have installed on it Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19). It is an armv6l GNU/Linux system.

When i try to run dotnet, it always responds with `./dotnet: No such file or directory`

I have made sure to make it an executable everytime using chmod +x dotnet, and checking if it is executable using ls -la, where it says `-rwxr-xr-x  1 1001  117 59928 Sep 13  2019 dotnet`

I have installed it using a script, like here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install

I also tried this method (which isnt supposed to work on my 32 bit system but i thought might as well try):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian

I can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: are you executing the above commands in the same directory? If the dotnet executable is there and shows the correct permissions (as it seems to be the case), then it clearly should be found. Maybe you have multiple installations around. What does `which dotnet` say?

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078275/net-core-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-raspbian?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

CD into the dotnet install folder and do `dotnet --info`

Output should be similar to this:
[image]

If you got this, it's just a matter of adding the dotnet folder to the path as exaplined in the MS link on your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud defintely be using docker for this. There are some great tutorials out there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows

This will simplify everything and this will also allow you to move your application to another location later on.

Do not hesitate to contact me for more help, I worked quite a bit on docker and dotnet recently.

Otherwise, it's just a problem about your env variables. When you launch the commend, it tries to locate dotnet. (Still think this is easier with docker).
Have a great day !